# Reading "return" as a char

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

Trying to teach a student how to use the scanf/printf statement in C. I realize this method is antiquated, but had to start somewhere. Also, Visual Studios is the standard for the university

Our code looks like the following

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
     char b = '';
     scanf(%c, &b);
     printf("%c", b);
     return 0;

}
```

However, it is reading the "return" as the character for b.
I'm not familiar with Visual studios, because I try to avoid it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Two typos: `char b = ""` and `scanf(%c, &b)`. Not clear as to why this would even compile.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey typo on my part in the question

Comment: copy paste ... a beautiful thing.  Show us your code as it is, not as you inaccurately copy it.  Sometimes the errors are masked by inaccurate copies.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey It is. It's just initializing the variable to NULL, maybe the CL.exe compiler is different. We tried to initialize it to null terminating char like you said, and still no such luck. We also did it without initializing the variable.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this is any different than in my question

Comment: `''` (empty character constant) is invalid syntax and should be an error.  It is not necessary to initialise `b` when you are going to read a value into it anyway, but if you want to (and it's not bad practice to initialise everything), the usual approach would be to initialise as `'\0'` or just `0`.  As Dan Farrell's answer says, you should be checking the return value of `scanf`.  I'm a little concerned that you are "teaching" somebody else without understanding the very basics...  `scanf` is not a good choice here.  You should be using `fgetc` or `getc`.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of thoughts.

Firstly, errors in posted program already pointed out.

Secondly, no introduction to `scanf` is complete without covering the fact that it returns the number matched inputs.

Finally, return character is a valid character.  This program will grab the fist character of input, so if you just enter `\n`, then `scanf` accurately grabs it.   ( *edit*: added output of the integer equivalent of the character entered to stress this point ).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
     char b;
     if( scanf("%c", &b) == 1){
        printf("Entered char # %i: %c\n", (int)b, b);
        return 0;
     }
     else {
            return 127;
     }
}
```

Comment: this would be great if it weren't for the fact that our initial input isn't a return, but rather the value and then a return

Comment: @rsheeler Did you actually run this program and try it?

Comment: Well the point I'm trying to make here is that it works as intended for me in "sane command line land" ( snarky, I know:) ).  Maybe there's characters on STDIN you're not expecting?  You might consider clearing stdin before asking for input, if that's the case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457789/clearing-stdin-buffer